# Is there a nomenclature for human physiology?

Tags: human-physiology, nomenclature, etymology

Back when I studied botany in high school, the teacher taught us the nomenclature for botanical terms. I think there should be something similar for human physiology. Understanding how the name was formed helps a lot while reading about the human body. Can you please point me to any resources (books or websites) on this topic?

Comment: Hey yasouser, I’m not sure if this is the case, but I’m curious if you’re actually referring to etymology rather than nomenclature. Your point “Understanding how the name was formed helps...” makes it seem like that’s the case. If so, most medical terminology textbooks have this information on word roots, prefixes, etc. and might also delve into Latin origins (I can recommend some if I’ve understood your question correctly).

Comment: Yes etymology of the medical terminology is what I'm looking for. I used the term nomenclature because the names are formed with certain rules, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Des Moines University](https://www.dmu.edu/medterms/overview/eponyms/) has an overview of medical terminology, for example:

- [Useful prefixes and suffixes](https://www.dmu.edu/medterms/basics/useful-prefixes-and-suffixes/)
- [Word roots for organs](https://www.dmu.edu/medterms/basics/word-roots-for-organs/)
- [Some general terms](https://www.dmu.edu/medterms/odds-and-ends/)
- System-specific terms, for example, for [circulatory system](https://www.dmu.edu/medterms/circulatory-system/)

The Free Dictionary has a [Medical Dictionary](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/physiology), which shows results from various dictionaries with basic etymology included.

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=physiology) is a detailed, general etymological dictionary, which includes a lot of medical terms.

Physiology as such may not have a lot of specific terms, but it is helpful to know basic anatomical and pathological terms when reading physiological texts.

[Schulic Medicine & Dentistry](https://www.schulich.uwo.ca/pathol/about_us/resources/glossary_of_medical_terms.html) has an one page glossary of ~400 medical terms.

[BC Campus](https://opentextbc.ca/anatomyandphysiology/chapter/1-6-anatomical-terminology/) has basic anatomical terms with pictures on one page.

Comment: Thanks for the Des Moines University weblink. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The book I'm most familiar with is *Medical Terminology: A Programmed Learning Approach to the Language of Health Care Second Edition* by Marjorie Canfield Willis. This book is great for what you're looking for, and I believe you can get the 2nd edition pretty cheap from multiple vendors.